# Swift and Combine. Problems when I recover one record from a local service

Tags: swift, rest, combine

I started to program with swift and I have problem with the call to a local service that returns for example:

{"idMember":14,"externalID":"001996.dce","email":null,"name":"Manu","isActive":true,"logDate":"2020-12-12 12:12:12","logUser":"asdasd"}

I tried this:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/member/findByExternalID/001996.dce")!
let token = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
           .map { $0.data }
           .decode(type: Member.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
           .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
              print(completion)
            }, receiveValue: { value in
               print("service has \(value) value")
           })
```

Member.swift:

```
struct Member: Codable, Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
let idMember:Int
var name:String
    
var logDate:Date
var logUser:String

var externalID:String
var email:String
var isActive:Bool

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case idMember, name,  logDate,  logUser,  externalID, email, isActive }
}
```

but never print info, the service is never invoked (I check it in the server log). I suppose this is a trivial question. But I didn't find what's wrong.

Comment: What do you do with the cancellable token? I see you store it in the `token` variable, but what happens afterwards? Note that if this token is deallocated, your data task cancels.

Comment: I don't do anything with it. I tried to simplify my code to find the problem, I use a breakpoint to watch the value of token. Do I need to do something with token in order to refresh it value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`token` is an AnyCancellable. If it goes out of scope before the actual networking has a chance to begin, it *will* cancel: that is what an AnyCancellable is. So if `token` is a mere local variable, your result is not surprising. You need to store `token` in an instance property that can persist at a higher level, long enough for the networking to take place.

The usual thing, actually, is not to assign the pipeline to something, but to add `.store` after `.sink` and store the pipeline in a `Set<AnyCancellable>` instance property, or similar.